# Raspberry pi camera h.264 codec licence

Tags: raspberry-pi, h.264, mpeg

I have pi camera module v2. I want to make life video stream.
I have tried to read h.264 license agreement but didn't understand: do I need to buy license for h.264 usage or it is included in camera's price?

Answer (score 0):

To encode the h264 with the Pi, you do not need a license. It has been paid by Pi.

https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=200855

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/new-video-features/